# Saving a file to Amazon Web Service s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

**PROBLEM**: I want to save to AWS S3 buckets from Amazon's own cluster without having to authenticate or use libraries. Basically I want to save data from a program running on Amazon clusters to a S3 bucket.

I am running some Python3 programs in Amazon Web Service (AWS) EMR cluster and I am trying to save files to a folder in an AWS S3 bucket, and if that folder doesn't exist, I want to create it.

The current way I am saving the file is something like the below. I have tried `with` method and it doesn't work either.

```
output = open("s3://mybucket/myfile.txt", "w+")
output.write("hello world\n")
```

For some reason, saving a RDD as `part-xxxxx` files to an S3 bucket works using the method from Spark RDDs without providing authentication:

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3://mybucket/")
```

Does the `saveAsTextFile()` work without authentication or does it authenticate somehow in the background?

If it doesn't require authentication to save files to S3 buckets from Amazon's clusters, is there a way to do this using Python's `open` method without requiring authentication like the way `saveAsTextFile()` RDD method does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EMR you probably don't need to do anything explicit to provide authentication.  The machines created in the EMR cluster are all assigned default **IAM roles** (created with your first EMR cluster) that should include permission to read and write to S3.

The **IAM roles** work by giving permissions to use various AWS APIs to specific machines as opposed to a specific AWS user account.  As long as the S3 requests are being sent from that box, you will not need to provide user authentication keys.

There are two options within your spark code to save data to S3:

1) Use Spark's own writing APIs for RDDs and DataFrames (**RDD.saveAsTextFile** and **DataFrame.write**).  These will work for S3, HDFS or local file system paths assuming all the right libraries are installed.  Which they will be on EMR.  Using this method will result in the normal _SUCCESS and part-##### files being written, but you can use Spark's coalesce(1) method to limit it to 1 partition file.

2) Use the **AWS SDK library** to manually write files to S3.

I tend to use option #1 because it will easily support different destination file systems without any changes to my code.  Also you don't need to worry about any additional libraries.

Another note, if you are using EMR then "s3://" is the correct prefix for any S3 endpoints, not s3n or s3a.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how did you manage to upload .part files to s3 without authentication even if you have tweaked s3 policies. I guess you might have added aws keys in the system environment as properties or in conf files.
In order to access aws resource, atleast its required to supply access key and secret key. Also, s3 scheme is deprecated now.
Following code works with hadoop-aws-2.8.0.jar and spark 2.1.
(note: I should have used s3a scheme as its the preferred over s3n (native scheme).

```
val spark = SparkSession
              .builder
              .appName("SparkS3Integration")
              .master("local[*]")
              .getOrCreate()
            spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", awsAccessKey)
            spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", awsSecretKey)

 val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4))
 rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3n://<bucket_name>/<path>")
```

Comment: s3n (native s3 file system) is now deprecated, in its place s3a is to be used. In Spark 2.0, following properties need to be configured in order to make use of s3a                                                                                                                     1. fs.s3a.access.key                                                                                   
2. fs.s3a.secret.key                                                                                               3. org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem